# MS Graph - Conversation delta API not working for some channels

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

For some channels, when conversations api is hit `/beta/teams/<team id>/channels/<channel id>/messages/delta`, we get an empty batch with next link. On hitting this next link, we get following error response.

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "BadRequest",
    "message": "Parameter 'DeltaToken' not supported for this request.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "b886b260-78ac-43b5-92d4-d0cb11136962",
      "date": "2019-12-09T09:39:16"
    }
  }
}
```

From the analysis of the same issue for the other channels, this issue seems to be occurring when channel has no new activity for around an year.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this is another symptom of this [Known Issue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/known-issues?context=graph%2Fapi%2Fbeta&view=graph-rest-beta#microsoft-teams):

> **Missing teams in list all teams**
>
> Some teams that were created in the past but haven't been used recently by a Microsoft Teams user aren't listed by list all teams. New teams will be listed. Certain old teams don't have a `resourceProvisioningOptions` property that contains "Team", which is set on newly created teams and teams that are visited in Microsoft Teams. In the future, we will set `resourceProvisioningOptions` on existing teams that have not been opened in Microsoft Teams.

You might be able to fix this by accessing the Cancel using the Teams client.