# Chat Messages Delta returning Bad Request

Tags: python-requests, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-teams

When calling `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/teams/{id}/channels/{id}/messages/delta` endpoint, I am getting a `400 (Bad Request) response.

[image]

I am experiencing the same issue in Microsoft Graph Explorer even after providing Admin Consent.

Below are some relevant posts I found where people are experiencing similar issues

- https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/7631
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/201576/when-i-call-the-api-to-get-message-list-by-using-d.html
- [MS Graph - Conversation delta API not working for some channels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59247541/ms-graph-conversation-delta-api-not-working-for-some-channels)

However the beta version of the aforementioned endpoint is functioning properly, but the beta version of Graph API is not advisable to be used in a production app.

Answer (score 0):

I just did a test on your problem, and I found that indeed as you said, when the beta version is used, the api call is successful, and when the v1.0 version is used, it reports a 400 error. This is strange because the documentation does not Too much explanation on this. So, I think this is an unknown error, you can [report](https://microsoftgraph.uservoice.com/forums/920506-microsoft-graph-feature-requests) your problem to Microsoft.